Pyspark - Databricks - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'
I am trying to write the data to a staging table using below code.
df_final.write.mode("overwrite").option("truncate", "true").jdbc(url=url, table= stg_tbl, properties=properties)

This is the error I get. It was working without issues, but suddenly it is throwing error.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
condition is expected, near ')'.

or

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An expression of
non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,
near 'AND'.

Below are the connection details
#Establish SQL DB Connection 

jdbchostname = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "sqlscope", key = "sqlservername")
jdbcport = 1433
db = "dbname"
username = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "sqlscope", key = "sqldbusername")
pwd = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "sqlscope", key = "sqldbpassword")

properties = {
    "user": username,
    "password": pwd,
    "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbchostname}:{jdbcport};database={db};user={username};password={pwd}"

Df code
df_final = df.withColumn('mapCol', \
                        func.create_map(func.lit('01'),df.Col1,
                                        func.lit('02'),df.Col2,
                                        func.lit('03'),df.Col3,
                                        func.lit('04'),df.Col4,
                                        func.lit('05'),df.Col5,
                                        func.lit('06'),df.Col6,
                                        func.lit('07'),df.Col7,
                                        func.lit('08'),df.Col8,
                                        func.lit('09'),df.Col9,
                                        func.lit('10'),df.Col10,
                                        func.lit('11'),df.Col11,
                                        func.lit('12'),df.Col12,
                                        func.lit('14'),df.Col13,
                                        func.lit('15'),df.Col14,
                                        func.lit('13'),df.Col15,
                                        func.lit('16'),df.Col16,
                                        func.lit('17'),df.Col17,
                                        func.lit('18'),df.Col18,
                                        func.lit('19'),df.Col19
                                    ) 
                    ).withColumn('SourceCode', lit(srcCode)).withColumn('InfCode', lit(infCode))

    df_final = df_final.select('*', func.explode(df_final.mapCol).alias('CatCode','Quantity'))

    df_final = df_final.select(
                'CatCode',
                'SourceCode',
                col('Date').alias('ReportDate'),
                substring('ID', -3, 3).alias('Company'),
                col('Org').alias('Organization'), 
                col('CC').alias('Country'),
                'Quantity',
                current_timestamp().alias('RecordCreationTimestamp'),
                current_timestamp().alias('RecordUpdateTimestamp'),
                'InfCode',
                'RIT_BIGINT_ACT'
                )



Pyspark - Databricks - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Typically occurs when there's a syntax issue or unexpected value in the code. In your case, the code snippet you provided seems correct, and I also tried its working fine for me.
Here are some points need to check

Make sure that no unexpected null values or special characters exist in any of the columns in df_final, which might create problems with the write operation.
Make sure that all of the columns should have the correct data types.
Clearing the cache in Databricks can sometimes resolve unexpected issues, especially if there have been recent changes or updates to your environment.

You can clear cache using following command:
spark.catalog.clearCache()


Restart the cluster to ensure that the changes take effect.

